# Canvas shown black randomly on Android 5

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, canvas, android-webview

We are developing a webapp in Apache Cordova. As javascript libraries we use jQuery, jQuery Mobile and Charts.js

Now something really strange happens in Android 5. Sometimes, without a clear pattern, graphs are not shown and we see a black area where the canvas should be. If we refresh the page or if we scroll down to cover the canvas and then up to show it, everything works again.
When the error happens, logcat says:

```
E/chromium(21275): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(6309)] [.Parent-Compositor-0xb4b6df60]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering or is not 'texture complete'
E/chromium(21275): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(6309)] [.Parent-Compositor-0xb4b6df60]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering or is not 'texture complete'
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a WebView update over the weekend and now the problem has disappeared for our two apps. dariosalvi may find that the charts are working fine now too. (A new feature of Android 5 is that the WebView is updated independently of the OS.)

Comment: good to know! the problem does seem to have disappeared in fact (although now I'm having another one with a click handler, but that's another story)

Comment: Can you point me to the correct WebView version that fixed the problem for you?

Comment: It should update on Android automatically but it is version 42.0.231.138.  You can search for Webview in Play Store to update manually if needed,

Answer (score 0):

I have found a possible reason:

if I remove jQuery Mobile animated transitions the problem seems to disappear. Even though I render the canvas after a "pagecontainershow", maybe the browser tries to render the canvas too early, but I'm only speculating.

Answer (score 0):

We're seeing something similar with our two PhoneGap apps that have worked fine across several platforms until Android 5. Our apps use jQuery and jQuery Mobile. I've updated to the latest libraries for both but it doesn't help. I have also tried turning off page transitions with no apparent effect.

In fact our biggest problem is that the screen often initially draws black where the canvas should be. Transitioning to another page and returning usually fixes it.

The canvas is also not being redrawn properly under some circumstances. I've checked that we're handling touchend and touchcancel as per the Chromium WebView migration notes (http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html) but it fact this worked fine in Android 4.4, which was the first to use the new WebView.

If you want to see this weird behaviour, install our 'WordEke' app from Google Play. Any suggestions welcome!

PS - Can confirm that I am also getting the render warnings. Here are the first few relevant lines from logcat (there are many render warnings):

```
E/chromium(13492): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(10748)] [.Parent-Compositor-0xb50fe510]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
E/chromium(13492): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(6309)] [.Parent-Compositor-0xb50fe510]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering or is not 'texture complete'
I/art     (  819): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 18772(846KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(16KB) LOS objects, 26% free, 44MB/60MB, paused 1.486ms total 108.916ms
E/chromium(13492): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(6309)] [.Parent-Compositor-0xb50fe510]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering or is not 'texture complete'
E/chromium(13492): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(6309)] [.Parent-Compositor-0xb50fe510]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering or is not 'texture complete'
```